# How to embed a portion of a website using iframe

Tags: html, iframe, google-sites

I am using a google site, and was wanting to embed a portion of a website - that portion being in the middle of the website. I have tried researching how to do it, but google sites doesn't like using div, or embed codes with a different format. While playing around with iframe, I could change the height and width of the iframe, but it all revolved around the top left corner. Is there anyway to change this so I can embed the specific portion of the website I want without having any of the other stuff surrounding it? 
Thanks

Comment: Some code will help.

Comment: A portion of a web*site* or a portion of a web*page*?

Comment: Oops - a webpage

Comment: There is no code currently as I am not aware of the way this can be achieved

Comment: Anyone? Any ideas?